# HTML/CSS side navigation bar not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple 2 column layout, the first column is side navbar and second column is content. I have a toggle button to hide/show side navbar. The logic that makes the sidebar responsive is that I have a css custom variable var(--navbar-width) which controls the width of the side navbar. For small screens the var(--navbar-width) is 0 and for others the var(--navbar-width) is 12rem. I have media query in place that sets the var(--navbar-width) value to 0 whenever screen size is smaller than 600px. Also when the toggle button is pressed the var(--navbar-width) value is toggled between 0 and 12rem.

Now the problem is when I press the toggle button the media query no longer works. I don't know why I am getting this behavior.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggleNavBar").click(function() {
    let width = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null).getPropertyValue("--navbar-width");

    if (width.trim() == "0") {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--navbar-width", "12rem");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--navbar-width", "0");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  --navbar-width: 12rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100vh, auto);
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #afafaf;
  width: var(--navbar-width);
  transition: width 200ms ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   :root {
    --navbar-width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">...</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main id="content">
    <button id="toggleNavBar">Toggle</button>
    <h1>...</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

The code is below also the link to codepen is https://codepen.io/isyedaliraza/pen/rNVbroq

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue your `navbar`. If you want smooth transition effect `navbar` need to `fixed` position. Below is the `code` and here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/MWwdbzj). I modify your `HTML` code. Also I haven't use your `CSS` and `JS` code. I'm not changing `CSS` property using **jQuery**. I did using add and remove `class`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <button id="navbarClose" class="close">x</button>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Four</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Five</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main class="main-wrapper" id="content">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="toggleNavBar">Toggle</button>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, a? Quam fugit quos eligendi voluptatum temporibus, libero tempora aperiam error culpa amet, iure distinctio sequi, obcaecati consequuntur quae a enim!</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eligendi ipsa labore dolorum qui accusamus magni cum maxime possimus iusto dolor tenetur minus nesciunt, ipsum autem assumenda, facere distinctio temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam nobis animi voluptas beatae. Pariatur iure, maxime fuga quam animi sapiente? Laborum voluptates similique neque qui! Dolore, et. Corporis, eveniet natus?</p>
  </main>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper{
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar{
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.navbar .close{
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar .close{
    display: block;
  }
}
.navbar.active{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar.active{
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.main-wrapper{
  background-color: #f8f8f7;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 280px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .main-wrapper{
    padding: 30px 15px;
  }
}
.main-wrapper.active{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .main-wrapper.active{
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('#toggleNavBar').on('click', function(){
    $('#content').toggleClass('active');
    $('#navbar').toggleClass('active');
  });
  $('#navbarClose').on('click', function(){
    $('#content').toggleClass('active');
    $('#navbar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Note: I'm using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) CSS for modify browser user agent style with normalize css property.

**I hope this will help you!**

Comment: No, I am trying to do this using CSS Grid. And my side navbar is working via media queries but the main problem is that when I press toggle button to show navbar media queries no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

Here I made this for you from scratch

```js
    var navElement = document.querySelector("nav"),
      mainElement = document.querySelector("main");
    document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
      navElement.classList.toggle("wzero");
      mainElement.classList.toggle("wfull");
    }
    document.body.onresize = function() {
      if(window.innerWidth > 600) {
        navElement.className = "";
        mainElement.className = "";
      }else {
        navElement.className = "wzero";
        mainElement.className = "wfull";
      }
    }
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    #container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    nav {
      width: 25%;
      background-color: gray;
      transition: width .5s ease;
    }
    main {
      width: 75%;
      background-color: lightgray;
      transition: width .5s ease;
    }
    .wzero {
      width: 0;
    }
    .wfull {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav>Nav</nav>
    <main><button>Toggle</button> Main</main>
  </div>
```